# How to find a row that contains a certain value from a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of 4,300 names called (mylist)

I have a dataframe (df) column (col1) with 3,130 rows. 
Each row contains a list of names within it.

I want to find every row that contains a value from mylist.

I have tried 3 methods but they all seem to give me the wrong answers.

1)

```
mask = df[col1].apply(lambda x: any(name in x for name in mylist)) 
   df1 = df[mask]
```

2)

```
row_containing_unique = list() 

    for row in df[col1]:
        for name in mylist: 
           if name in row: 
            row_containing_unique.append(row)
```

3)

```
for name in mylist:
      if name in mylist: 
         mask = df[col1].isin(mylist)
         df1 = df[mask]
```

The expected result is a dataframe where each row has a value from mylist.

Comment: As far as my understanding of the problem, a simple `df[df[col1].isin(mylist)]` should be sufficient to get a dataframe with all rows which contain names from `mylist`.

Comment: @amanb I had initially thought the same but looking at the wording I actually think that each value in col1 of the DataFrame is itself a list of names. Although if that's the case then method 1) above using `apply` and `any` should be working fine so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you share a sample of the dataframe and expected output.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataframe (using `df.head(5)`)? Might help clear up some of the wording

Comment: the issue is each row in df[col1] contains a list itself. when i do df[col1].isin(mylist) i get an error that reads  <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001AAEC4D0260> returned a result with an error set

Comment: @thesilkworm yes that is the issue.

Comment: In that case I don't understand why your first method using `apply` and `any` doesn't work, it seems to me like it should. As others have commented, posting a small sample of data and actual versus expected results will help people to find a solution.

Comment: @thesilkworm the reason I know the output is incorrect is because I have a total of 3130 rows, the output i get is 1900 rows. Meaning if i ran the same line of code to find the amount of rows that do not include a name from my list I should get back 1230 but instead I get 907.

Answer (score 0):

## Note, this is to take the place of a string of comments

I will remove this when a suitable answer is accepted or clarification is provided by OP.

Based on the wording of the problem, you have a dataframe with a single column, and each row is a list of names. You are attempting to filter out rows based on the condition that they need to contain at least one name that's within a master list.

Based on that description, I have arrived at the same solution as what you have provided in option 1:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

lst = ['john', 'mike', 'jen', 'april', 'rita', 'aaron', 'brian']
other_names = ['carter', 'mckenzie', 'tyler', 'erick', 'holly'] + lst
# will now contain lists of varying length
df = pd.DataFrame([[[random.choice(other_names) for i in range(random.randint(1,5))]] for i in range(25)], columns=['names'])

df.head(5)
                           names
0                        [erick]
1             [rita, aaron, jen]
2    [aaron, tyler, brian, rita]
3                         [john]
4  [carter, holly, erick, aaron]



# for y in x is iterating over the list in each row
df.loc[df['names'].apply(lambda x: any(y in lst for y in x))]
                                    names
1                      [rita, aaron, jen]
2             [aaron, tyler, brian, rita]
3                                  [john]
4           [carter, holly, erick, aaron]
5                                  [john]

# and to show the converse, no membership in lst
df.loc[df['names'].apply(lambda x: not any(y in lst for y in x))]
             names
0          [erick]
16         [tyler]
21         [tyler]
22  [erick, tyler]
23         [erick]
```

Can you provide some sample data, the actual output of your solution, and the expected output? Otherwise, we won't be able to help

Comment: Sorry this is one of my first times asking a question and do not know how to write questions in the format you are posting them....you are on the write track of what I need but each row in original dataframe has a different value within each list ...ex: row 0 has 5 names, row 1 has 7 names, row 2 has 1 name. I tried your solution just now and it gives me the same result as my 2nd solution posted. So each row has a  different number of elements inside the list. I want to return any row that contains a name from mylist

Comment: No worries, I'd highly recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This does return the rows that have members contained within the parent list. So take my example, what would you expect to see that you do not?

Comment: After looking at your example, and trying it out on my code i see it only returns specific columns that include 1 name. It doesn't iterate through the whole list

Comment: Alright, I think *iterate through the whole list* implies something different than I am thinking. The lambda function does iterate through the list in each row, it's just `any` will return `True` for any row that contains *at least* one name in `mylist`

Comment: Which list are you trying to iterate over?

Comment: Trying to iterate over every row (each row consists of a list but element count in each list is different) and find any row that contains a value from mylist

Comment: Right, the `any` doesn't need the length of the lists to be the same. Back to the crux of the issue, why does the `lambda` not work? What are you expecting that you aren't seeing?

Comment: @muchappreciated I'll make an edit to my comment/answer to illustrate the point

Comment: I receive a dataframe (newdf) with 167 rows from the original 4300 which seemed small. I did a spot check of a name from mylist using the following code: 

mask = df.col1.apply(lambda x 'jessie' in x)
df1 = df[mask] 

and this returned 2 rows, while those 2 rows were excluded from newdf

This is how i knew data was missing

Comment: Alright, so this could be an issue of how the df/list were created. It's very possible that there are leading/trailing spaces. What I would do is find the rows that are affected by your experiment, as well as entries in the list. Once you have found them, have the list entries be `mylist` and the offending rows be `df` by putting them as your example code in the question

Comment: How are you creating this dataframe? Are you reading it from a file?

Comment: pulling the dataframe from api data

Comment: And how about your list?

Comment: the list is created by finding the unique values found between 2 lists

Comment: oh boy. And how were those made? The reason I'm asking is because *any* deviation in the strings will cause a non-match. Trailing space, leading space, upper-case letter, etc

Comment: For example: `'xyz ' == 'xyz'` returns `False`, as does `'Xyz' == 'xyz'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've tried with set intersection on each list in the row of the series & the `names` list. Hope this helps resolve your problem.

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['john','sam','tim'], ['vicki', 'tom', 'val'], ['mike', 'bob', 'sean'], ['dean','kevin
    ...: ', 'sandra']], 'B':[5,6,7,8]})

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                       A  B
0       [john, sam, tim]  5
1      [vicki, tom, val]  6
2      [mike, bob, sean]  7
3  [dean, kevin, sandra]  8

In [14]: names = ['john','tom', 'sean']

In [43]: df[df.A.apply(lambda x:any(set(x).intersection(names)))]
Out[43]:
                   A  B
0   [john, sam, tim]  5
1  [vicki, tom, val]  6
2  [mike, bob, sean]  7
```